# Azure Database For MySql - How to see the successful backup and restore logs?

Tags: mysql, backup, azure, restore

I am using Azure Database for MySQL, vcore GpV2 and had opted for Geo-redundant backup during Database creation. According to the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-backup),

> Generally, full backups occur weekly, differential backups occur twice
>   a day, and transaction log backups occur every five minutes.

But how shall I know whether backups are actually happening automatically? Where are the logs?

I checked in Activity Log but there aren't any backup logs coming.

Comment: Can you check this `Azure Database for MySQL automatically creates server backups and stores them in user configured locally redundant or geo-redundant storage.`?

Comment: I want the logs (and not actual backed up db) after a backup gets created at locally redundant or geo-redundant storage for audit purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no backup logs. The backup of PaaS databases is handled as part of the platform and the logs for this are not accessible to the user. The assumption is that if you are going to use a PaaS service that you trust the provider to do these things for. If you don't then you should run in IaaS.